# Using NPM packages in Meteor package.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I'm trying to use the `glob` NPM module to simplify adding files to my Meteor package:

```
Package.on_test(function(api) {
  Npm.depends({
    "glob": "3.2.7"
  });

  var glob = Npm.require("glob");
  api.add_files(glob.sync("styles/**/*.styl"), "client");
  api.add_files(glob.sync("tests/styles/**/*.@(styl|css)"), "client");
});
```

This won't work, because the `glob` dir won't be added to `.npm/package/node_modules` until later. If I try to run `meteor test-packages ./` I get the error:

> can't find npm module 'glob'. Did you forget to call 'Npm.depends'?

However, I can trick Meteor into making this work by doing this:

```
Package.on_test(function(api) {
  Npm.depends({
    "glob": "3.2.7"
  });

  var glob = Npm.require("glob");
  if (glob) {
    api.add_files(glob.sync("styles/**/*.styl"), "client");
    api.add_files(glob.sync("tests/styles/**/*.@(styl|css)"), "client");
  }
});
```

Now, the first time I run `meteor test-packages`, the app loads the NPM dependencies and then crashes. If I run it again, the `glob` package has been added and everything works correctly. So I'm wondering if there is a better way to use Npm modules other than Underscore and the built in modules like `fs` and `path` inside of `package.js`?

I realize that I can emulate this functionality with `fs`, but the globpattern syntax is much more terse and readable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will help but there is a 'cheat' way to add an npm module.

If you're testing you could install 'glob' globally with `npm install glob -g` and use something like this:

```
var glob = eval("require('glob');");
```

Meteor's linker module isn't able to interpret this and change it so you can link up to npm modules directly so you could use this to attach to the global npm module instead of the local one.

The reason `Npm.require` doesn't work in package.js on the first run is because `package.js` is used by linker to create the idea of what npm modules are needed and how to link them up.

Afterwards the project is run and the npm module can be used with `Npm.require` in the files associated with `api.add_files`.

But if you want to use some logic on deciding what files to add you have to get access to something a bit lower level and this is what running the code in `eval()` lets you do.

Another option would be to install the Npm module manually and use eval to load it up. Its very low level though so it might be more hassle than its worth. The details on how npm files can be installed can be found at https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/tools/meteor_npm.js

Its basically creating a 'shrinkwrap' then installing the npm modules.

Comment: I ended up including the directory `.npm/package/node_modules/glob/` in my git commit. This fixes it and the build is passing locally and on Travis CI. I'm not sure what the side effects are, though.

Comment: There shouldn't be any side effects, as long as there are no binaries involved since they wouldn't work on another architecture/os. I checked the npm module and there aren't any of these I checked as far as the npm module and its first dependency but there were further dependencies that might have a binary file not too sure.

Comment: Nope looks like it's 100% JavaScript.